QML gradient border color issue when trying to center the popup
I'm trying to create a gradient color border for a button on a Popup. It seems good if I don't try to centering the popup. I have no word to call the name or describe the issue. Please take a look at the border of the Cancel button in the attached image and the code.  (I'm using Qt 6.3)

import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
//import QtQuick3D
import Qt5Compat.GraphicalEffects

ApplicationWindow {
    id: root
    width: 666
    height: 777
    visible: true
    color: "grey"
    Button
    {
        width: 111
        height: 44
        text: "Show"
        onClicked: menu.open()
    }
    Popup {
        id: menu
        width: (559)
        height: (643)

        modal: true
        dim: false
        focus: true
        closePolicy: Popup.CloseOnEscape | Popup.CloseOnPressOutsideParent

        background: Rectangle {
            //        color: "transparent"
            border.color: "transparent"
            LinearGradient {
                anchors.fill: parent
                start: Qt.point(0, 0)
                end: Qt.point(0, parent.height)
                gradient: Gradient {
                    GradientStop { position: 0.0; color: "#29395D" }
                    GradientStop { position: 1.0; color: "#1C2341" }
                }
            }
        }

    //    Component.onCompleted: {
    //    x: (parent.width - width) / 2
    //    y: (parent.height - height) / 2
    ////            anchors.centerIn = parent
    ////                    anchors.centerIn = Overlay.overlay
    //    }
//        onAboutToShow: anchors.centerIn = Overlay.overlay
        anchors.centerIn : Overlay.overlay

        Button {
            id: okBt
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.topMargin: (410)
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            width: (276)
            height: (41)
            text: "OK"
//            font.family: FontModel.family
            font.pixelSize: (16)
            font.weight: Font.Normal    //400
            contentItem: Text {
                text: parent.text
                font: parent.font
                color: "#FFFFFF"
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                elide: Text.ElideRight
            }
            flat: true
            background: Rectangle {
                implicitWidth: (276)
                implicitHeight: (41)
                radius: (6)
                border.width: 0
                gradient: Gradient {
                    orientation: Gradient.Horizontal
                    GradientStop { position: 1.0; color: "#2F3D6D" }
                    GradientStop { position: 0.0; color: "#3C5199" }
                }
            }
        }

        Button {
            id: cancelBt
    //        visible: false
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.topMargin: (471)
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            width: (276)
            height: (41)
            text: "Cancel"
//            font.family: FontModel.family
            font.pixelSize: (16)
            font.weight: Font.Normal    //400
            contentItem: Text {
                text: parent.text
                font: parent.font
                color: "#FFFFFF"
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                elide: Text.ElideRight
            }
            flat: true
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: gradientBorder
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.topMargin: (471)
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            width: (276)
            height: (41)
            radius: (6)
            z: cancelBt.z + 11
            color: "transparent"
            Rectangle {
                id: bd
                anchors.fill: parent
                radius: parent.radius
                gradient: Gradient {
                    orientation: Gradient.Horizontal
                    GradientStop { position: 1.0; color: "#2F3D6D" }
                    GradientStop { position: 0.0; color: "#3C5199" }
                }
                layer.enabled: true
                layer.effect: OpacityMask {
                    invert: true
                    maskSource: Item {
                        width: bd.width
                        height: bd.height
                        Rectangle {
                            anchors.centerIn: parent
                            width: parent.width -2
                            height: parent.height -2
                            radius: gradientBorder.radius
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


My guess is this is an issue of half and full pixel alignment. Try to set the anchors.alignWhenCentered: false on the button https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-item.html#anchors.alignWhenCentered-prop

@iam_peter: the issue is still there.

The issue you encountering has definitely something to do with half pixel rounding. This is especially an issue when using texture/layers, because internally the textures size (sourceSize) gets rounded when creating textures from floating point positioned/sized items. I didn't had a proper look at your example when I've created my comment.
In order to work around the issue you should tweak your sizes in order for the items to be pixel aligned. In my example below I've made all your odd sizes even so the anchoring logic doesn't place items on half pixels.
Also instead of using OpacityMask to create a cutout, I've used a LinearGradient from the Qt5Compat.GraphicalEffects and an invisible Rectangle that gets assigned as the source.

import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
import Qt5Compat.GraphicalEffects

ApplicationWindow {
    id: root
    width: 666
    height: 777
    visible: true
    color: "grey"

    Button {
        width: 111
        height: 44
        text: qsTr("Show")
        onClicked: popup.open()
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }

    Popup {
        id: popup
        width: 560
        height: 644
        modal: true
        dim: false
        focus: true
        closePolicy: Popup.CloseOnEscape | Popup.CloseOnPressOutsideParent
        anchors.centerIn : Overlay.overlay

        background: Rectangle {
            border.color: "transparent"

            LinearGradient {
                anchors.fill: parent
                start: Qt.point(0, 0)
                end: Qt.point(0, parent.height)
                gradient: Gradient {
                    GradientStop { position: 0.0; color: "#29395D" }
                    GradientStop { position: 1.0; color: "#1C2341" }
                }
            }
        }

        Button {
            id: okBt
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.topMargin: 410
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            width: 276
            height: 42
            text: qsTr("OK")
            font.pixelSize: 16
            font.weight: Font.Normal
            flat: true

            contentItem: Text {
                text: parent.text
                font: parent.font
                color: "#FFFFFF"
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                elide: Text.ElideRight
            }

            background: Rectangle {
                implicitWidth: okBt.width
                implicitHeight: okBt.height
                radius: 6

                gradient: Gradient {
                    orientation: Gradient.Horizontal
                    GradientStop { position: 1.0; color: "#2F3D6D" }
                    GradientStop { position: 0.0; color: "#3C5199" }
                }
            }
        }

        Button {
            id: cancelBt
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.topMargin: 471
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            width: 276
            height: 42
            text: qsTr("Cancel")
            font.pixelSize: 16
            font.weight: Font.Normal
            flat: true

            contentItem: Text {
                text: parent.text
                font: parent.font
                color: "#FFFFFF"
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                elide: Text.ElideRight
            }

            Rectangle {
                id: dummy
                width: cancelBt.width
                height: cancelBt.height
                color: "transparent"
                border.width: 2
                radius: 6
                visible: false
            }

            background: LinearGradient {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                //anchors.alignWhenCentered: false
                width: dummy.width
                height: dummy.height
                start: Qt.point(0, 0)
                end: Qt.point(dummy.width, 0)
                source: dummy
                gradient: Gradient {
                    GradientStop { position: 1.0; color: "#2F3D6D" }
                    GradientStop { position: 0.0; color: "#3C5199" }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

